# problem with torch_scatter: undefined symbol

Tags: pytorch

When running `import torch_scatter` on a GPU, I met the following error:

```
OSError: /scratch/ssd001/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch_scatter/_version_cuda.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c106detail12infer_schema20make_function_schemaENS_8ArrayRefINS1_11ArgumentDefEEES4_
```

Does anyone know how to fix this OSError? Thank you! My python version is 3.6 with CUDA 10.2 and pytorch 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to version unmatch. Get your correct `torch_scatter` version [here](https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/index.html).